# Alternative to `ping`

Tags: arch-linux, ping, software-rec

I'm searching for an alternative to the popular `ping` command. Looking to perform statistic analysis on latency data I'll retrieve somehow, but `ping`'s output format is a) not properly documented and b) contains variable precision and I'd like to avoid introducing the associated disparity to my data. What I'm looking for is a program that

- lets the user ping a server, returning RTT in ms in a stable, precise format (the more precise, the better, I'd like to avoid discrete bucketing of low latencies), and
- is distributed under Linux (x86_64 Arch Linux and Debian preferably)

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

For one, there's [fping](https://packages.debian.org/buster/fping).

The man page mentions e.g. this:

> `-C n` Similar to `-c`, but the per-target statistics are displayed in
> a format designed for automated response-time statistics gathering.
> For example:
>
> ```
> % fping -C 5 -q somehost
> somehost : 91.7 37.0 29.2 - 36.8
> ```
>
> shows the response time in milliseconds for each of the five requests, with the "-" indicating that no response was received to the
> fourth request.

And it takes more than one host at the same time, if you like:

```
$ fping -q -C 3 ns1 dns.google
ns1        : 0.37 0.19 0.31
dns.google : 25.44 25.43 25.38
```